# Unbind sigaction handler

Tags: c, gcc, posix, signals

I've succesfully attached a handler function to SIG_INT and SIG_KILL but now I would like to be able to "unbind" the handler at a certain point (after a fork to be precise). This is how I attach the handler:

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = interrupt_handler;
sigempty(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

sigaction(SIG_INT, &sa, NULL);
sigaction(SIG_KILL, &sa, NULL);
```

interrupt_handler only prints something.

Comment: You can't "catch"a SIGKILL signal. It will always terminate the program.

Comment: @Milan: Doug McIlroy can catch SIGKILL. http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sinclair/doug/

Comment: @Milan thanks for the heads up, didn't really needed it to catch a kill anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to restore the previous disposition:

```
struct sigaction sa, oldsa;

/* Change it but save previous state. */
sigaction(SIG_INT, &sa, &oldsa);

/* ... */

/* Restore previous stuff. */
sigaction(SIG_INT, &oldsa, NULL);
```